# Docusign - no redirect url for embedded signing

Tags: docusignapi

We have one use case in our app's embedded signing flow where a specific type of user does not need to be redirected back to our app upon signing. Is there a way to direct them to the default 'signing completed' page on the DocuSign site? I tried:

1. not passing up a `returnUrl`
2. setting that value to `nil` or an empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, easy one:
use - https://postsign.docusign.com/postsigning/en/finish-signing
as your redirectUrl

Enjoy.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Is there a similar page that we can edit per chance?

Comment: if you want your own page, you will need to host it.